# codeigniter UTF-8 language works or doesn't work?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, codeigniter-2

I'm facing a weird actions by codeiginter especially when it comes to using different languages. I had to translate some pages in the `system/language/arabic` and `system/language/japanese` as well and changed the chartset to `UTF-8`in the config.php file, but when I test it through the form validation for example, it gives me ????????? characters as if these languages are not recognized even by the unicode.

any idea how to get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it urned out that I need to do some trick in here. For Arabic language I had to use unicoding html to make it like symbols then add them to my php or html. and it works perfect. For Japanese language, it is just adjusting unicoding in the config file at codeigniter. And that's it.